# Can't Install UVC drivers: "implicit declaration of function 'x' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]"

Tags: 12.04, drivers, compiling, webcam, uvc

I am working on a project for my final year project which involves the use of a web-cam. I bought an external one and tried to install new drivers for it. Now my integrated web-cam won't work.

My webcam is an Acer crystal eye.

I have tried re-installing the UVC drivers following these steps:

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build
./build
```

However I get the following error during the build:

```
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c: In function 'mt9p031_clk_setup':
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:226:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'devm_clk_get' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:226:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c: In function 'mt9p031_power_on':
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:287:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'clk_prepare_enable' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c: In function 'mt9p031_power_off':
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:310:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'clk_disable_unprepare' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c: In function 'mt9p031_probe':
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:961:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'devm_regulator_get' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:961:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:962:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:963:18: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.c:1035:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'devm_gpio_request_one' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l/mt9p031.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40-generic'
make[1]: *** [default] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tom/Downloads/media_build/v4l'
make: *** [all] Error 2
build failed at ./build line 452.
```

If anybody could help I would really appreciate it as I don't have much time left to work on the project!

Answer (score 0):

The errors you see are caused by the C++ source code which you got with the git clone command from the site. They have an inherent bug(implicit function declaration), so you should file a bug against the package. You could try editing `Makefile` in gedit, or if `build` is a shell script, editing that to remove `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` from any commands.